# How to reauthorize credit cards and Paypal in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How to reauthorize credit cards and Paypal in netsuite after some criteria is not met.

Thanks
Prakash

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the payment processor. For Cybersource you have to edit the record and modify the "Auth" field to specify the amount to authorize, and then check the checkbox field called "Get Authorization" and save the record. After the record has been saved there should be a new line in the payment events list under the billing tab.